# How do I respond to "family emergency"?

Tags: politeness

Someone tells me that he is sorry but he has been absent for a family emergency.

Can I say "I hope your family is fine"? I wondered if that's polite in English-speaking culture.

Comment: I'd probably say "I hope your family is OK now" or "I hope the emergency has been resolved."

Comment: I would respond as "I hope your family emergency gets resolved quickly"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In English-speaking culture, I often hear people apologize for the misfortune of the other person. It's common to say something like "I'm sorry to hear that. I hope everything is ok."

Comment: Family emergencies don't always involve misfortune.  For example, if your mother had procrastinated at turning in a winning lottery ticket, driving her to the lottery office at the last minute is a family emergency.